# Error when install Material UI in Angular 2

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material

I am trying to implement material UI.
I follow all steps from Material UI Website.
But when i use "npm start" command, it show errors as below.

```
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button/button.d.ts(40,22): error TS2420: Class 'MdButton' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDis
able'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdButton'.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/button/button.d.ts(40,39): error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MdBut
tonBase' is not a constructor function type.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/checkbox/checkbox.d.ts(43,22): error TS2420: Class 'MdCheckbox' incorrectly implements interface '
CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdCheckbox'.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/checkbox/checkbox.d.ts(43,41): error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof M
dCheckboxBase' is not a constructor function type.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/radio/radio.d.ts(24,22): error TS2420: Class 'MdRadioGroup' incorrectly implements interface 'CanD
isable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdRadioGroup'.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/radio/radio.d.ts(24,43): error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MdRadio
GroupBase' is not a constructor function type.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.d.ts(14,22): error TS2420: Class 'MdSlideToggle' incorrectly implements
interface 'CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdSlideToggle'.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slide-toggle/slide-toggle.d.ts(14,44): error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) &
typeof MdSlideToggleBase' is not a constructor function type.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slider/slider.d.ts(26,22): error TS2420: Class 'MdSlider' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDis
able'.
 Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MdSlider'.
node_modules/@angular/material/typings/slider/slider.d.ts(26,39): error TS2507: Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MdSli
derBase' is not a constructor function type.
node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts(8,119): error TS2305: Module '"D:/NG2/ngMat/node_modules/@angular/an
imations/browser"' has no exported member 'ɵDomAnimationEngine'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(7,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'describe'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(12,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(19,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'beforeEach'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(25,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(25,39): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(27,3): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'it'.
src/app/app.component.spec.ts(30,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! materialui@1.0.0 build: `tsc -p src/`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the materialui@1.0.0 build script 'tsc -p src/'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the materialui package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc -p src/
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs materialui
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls materialui
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\NG2\ngMat\npm-debug.log

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! materialui@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the materialui@1.0.0 prestart script 'npm run build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the materialui package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     npm run build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs materialui
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls materialui
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\NG2\ngMat\npm-debug.log
```

I tested angular web app. Angular app working fine.
But when i install material UI then i got these errors.
I am new in Material UI.
Anyone who solve this problem ?

Comment: You realize that material ui is a set of components made for react, not for angular2/4 right?

Comment: No i am using Angular Material UI. you can check here [Angular Material UI](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started).

Comment: ah ok, in that case the name is just angular material

Comment: the fact that you get this npm ERR! materialui@1.0.0 prestart: `npm run build` in the error log means that you probably installed the project that I meant

Comment: I want to use Angular Material in angular project. But when i install Angular Material according to the given steps in Angular Material 's official website. Then some errors shown in commandline. i want to solve that Errors.

Comment: if by material UI you mean http://www.material-ui.com/ then you cant use it with angular, as I already mentioned. Add your package.json into your question for further help

Comment: Angular Material Means https://material.angular.io/

Comment: Then why do you use the tag material-ui, did you read the description of the tag? why do you refer to it as material ui in the question? naming matters. Please add your package.json, otherwise I cant help

Comment: I think Angular UI & Material UI is same. So that i am used material UI. But now i am understand both are different. and i am unable to add package.json because of word limit restriction of comment box.

Comment: What versions of angular and material are you using? From the logs is look like there is someting with the `FormModule`. Is it part of your dependencies and have you imported it in you AppModule?

Comment: `node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts(8,119): error TS2305: Module '"D:/NG2/ngMat/node_modules/@angular/an
imations/browser"' has no exported member 'ɵDomAnimationEngine'.` did you get any solution for this error ?